# MySecondViewController won't display correctly

Tags: objective-c, uikit, xcode4

I have programmatically created a second view controller (MySecondViewController) which was all done and hooked up without using the visual object editor.

My problem is that when I run the app, only the original view controller (HelloWorldViewController) comes up; the second view controller does not show up. When I click on the view for HelloWorldViewController, nothing comes up.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

windowBasedAppAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//-- Add a forward reference to the HelloWorldViewController class --

@class HelloWorldViewController;

@interface windowBasedAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    //-- create an instance of the view controller--
    HelloWorldViewController *viewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

//--Expose the view controller as a property--
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet HelloWorldViewController *viewController;

@end
```

windowBasedAppAppDelegate.m

```
#import "windowBasedAppAppDelegate.h"
#import "HelloWorldViewController.h"
#import "MySecondViewController.h"

@implementation windowBasedAppAppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

//-- a second view controller object--
MySecondViewController *mySecondViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //-- add the new view to the current window--
    //-- instantiate the second view controller --
    mySecondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:nil
                          bundle:nil];

   // -- add the view from the second controller --
   //[window addSubview:mySecondViewController.view];

   [window addSubview:viewController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [MySecondViewController release];
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

MySecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MySecondViewController : UIViewController {
    //-- create two outlets, label and button --
    UILabel *label;
    UIButton *button;

}

//-- expose the outlets as properties --

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button;

// -- declaring the IBAction ---
- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (id)sender;

@end
```

MySecondViewController.h

```
#import "MySecondViewController.h"


@implementation MySecondViewController

@synthesize label, button;

- (IBAction) buttonClicked: (id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Invoked!" message:@"Button clicked"     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

HelloWorldViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController {

}

@end
```

HelloWorldViewController.m

## import "HelloWorldViewController.h"

```
@implementation HelloWorldViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
    }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Added code from MySecondViewController.m

```
//-- add the views to the view window --
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:1 withSubviewAtIndex:0];
    self.view = view;
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: You should really add the implementation of `HelloWorldViewController` for this.

Comment: How are you loading the `MySecondViewController` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `view` is being initialized and that it has a proper frame, the problem could be this sequence of code,

```
[window addSubview:mySecondViewController.view];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

As the `viewController`'s `view` will have the same frame, it will be added over `mySecondViewController`'s `view`. So you will have to remove the second line for the view to show up.

Comment: In the windowBasedAppAppDelegate.m file, I noticed that I had commented out [window addSubview:mySecondViewController.view]; Removed comment marks, but still did not load. Should I put it in a different place?

Comment: Well, so is the `view` property properly initialized somewhere? Is that what you do in the `// custom initialization` part?

Comment: So should I expose view as a property in the windowBasedAppAppDelegate.h and .m files?

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Can you do `NSLog(@"%@", mySecondViewController.view);` after you do `[window addSubview:mySecondViewController.view];` and let me know what it logs?

Comment: Here's the output: 2011-06-24 19:28:47.166 windowBasedApp[899:207] <UIView: 0x4b3ed70; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x4b3fd90>>

Answer (score 0):

You never actually push the new view controller onto the screen.

```
 mySecondViewController = [[MySecondViewController alloc]
                      initWithNibName:nil
                      bundle:nil];

// -- add the view from the second controller --
//[window addSubview:mySecondViewController.view];

   [window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

You add viewController.view, (which should be undefined...), but not mySecondViewController.view.

Also, programHasFinishedLaunching may not be the best possible place to push it.  If I were you, I'd put a button on the front page that pushes the new view in, it's easier that way.

Comment: Thank you. Am learning about view hierarchy from the book Beginning iOS4 Application Development, and I added some code in to adjust the view hierarchy. When I tried to run it (see added code above), I got an error message that 'view' is undeclared. What can I do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: At a guess, it's because you don't have a nib-name.  The nib (XIB) file is where the view is instantiated.  Since you don't have a nib, you need to create the actual self.view on your second view controller ([UIView view] should do it).